# Calculate time elapsed from log timestamps using Ruby

Tags: ruby, timestamp, datetime

I am parsing a log and would like an elegant way of calculating the difference between these time stamps shown below:

[Mar 2, 2010 1:54:40 AM]
[Mar 4, 2010 10:54:40 PM]

I've looked at DateTime however I wasnt sure if it was ncessary to seperate the Date from the actual time part and create a Time object.  If there is an easier way please fire away.

Regards.
Snappy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only `DateTime` class:

```
require 'date'
d1, d2 = 'Mar 2, 2010 1:54:40 AM', 'Mar 4, 2010 10:54:40 PM'
diff = DateTime.parse(d2) - DateTime.parse(d1)
hours,minutes,seconds,frac = Date.send(:day_fraction_to_time, diff)
# => [69, 0, 0, 01]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [chronic gem](http://chronic.rubyforge.org) to parse the two times to obtain two time objects then [substract](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000275)

Comment: Thanks that does work - wish it could interpret the Mar into March so that it could add the difference of days to the time difference..